# Do all applications that run on Windows use the Windows API?

Tags: winapi

I am trying to understand how code, regardless of the language, works. Specifically thinking about software that runs on Windows.

Is my understanding correct that every built in function of a particular language maps to an exposed function in the Windows API when writing software for the Windows platform?

I guess my question can be even more generally, can a language do anything outside of what the OS provides? If so, how? What is an example of this?

Comment: Theoretically not necessarily, but in practice yes. That is the API that is used to program in Windows. (Theoretical: there is a native NT API which is lower level and isn’t used in regular applications, as well as you could go to syscall level if you wanted to, but it isn’t really useful)

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Aren't NT API and syscall functions provided by the OS? What is the difference between these and the Windows API?

Comment: Before virtualization became mainstream, the WINE Windows Emulator was created to run Windows programs on Linux by supplying a compatible API layer. As I recall, it worked fine with simple applications but failed on most “real-world” commercial apps, because those apps bypassed the APIs (or relied on undocumented features,

Comment: @AlexR there was nothing undocumented in most real world apps, nor they bypass the API. It was simply that WINE implemented only a small percentage of the functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theoretical and a practical answer to this.

Practical: yes.

The WinAPI is the API everything uses to do things on Windows. It’s stable and compatible between versions so you can write whatever you want with it and it will work on practically any version of Windows given you don’t use any APIs that aren’t present in an old version. There isn’t any other interface to talk to the operating system properly.

Any language or platform that wants to work on top of this will call WinAPI. C libraries, Python, etc all are written so that they work on top of it (often other languages use C or C++ libraries which use WinAPI).

Theoretical: no.

Windows itself includes a [Native API](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/11831.the-windows-native-api.aspx) which is the actual OS interface and WinAPI is built on top of this. It is not really used if it’s not necessary since it’s not really documented. It’s used in a couple of Windows components that need to run before the other parts of the system are running and you can build applications linking to this API. But since it’s undocumented it’s not really reasonable and may change whenever.

There is also the [syscall level](https://github.com/j00ru/windows-syscalls). Several Windows components provide the lower level services for operations done on the WinAPI level. You can write, for example, an assembly program and use the syscalls directly if you want to. Mostly you don’t want to so this is more of a theoretical rather than practical answer to different platforms communicating with the OS. These also may change based on the OS.

WinAPI is basically only one subsystem that runs on the NT kernel. For example, Windows Subsystem for Linux is another one which implements its own syscalls which are then translated to Windows ones. There has also been a POSIX subsystem previously.

So all in all it depends on which level you look at it, but the practical answer is yes. Everything practically runs on WinAPI.

Comment: OK but Windows API, Native API, and Syscall are all things provided by the OS. In that sense, a language written on top of the OS is only at the mercy of the OS right? The language can't do anything that doesn't map to SOMETHING provided by the OS is that correct?

Comment: @vchester That’s also a theoretical yes and no :) The program can for example ask for access to hardware directly from the OS, but that goes again to the land of “you wouldn’t start writing device drivers and get them approved and signed for fun.” So yes, for general purpose applications there is no access to the computer other than through the OS provided services. Anything else is a bug and a security issue.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *The program can for example ask for access to hardware directly from the OS*? Are you saying that this function used in the language does not map to something the OS provides? What does it map to?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Even if an application exits immediately, it uses a windows call.
So it is not only theoretical. In theory, as in practice, every Windows application uses the API, because there is nothing else to use.

Even if you try to rewrite each functionality you are about to use, you would eventually have to install a driver, and this also mean you would use the API.